# How is FormData actually handled by a server?

Tags: html5, forms

I am using an embedded system with a web server. I really have no way to dig deep into the webserver and see how it works, so I am asking a more general question:

How do servers or back-end scripts (like PHP) handle HTML `FormData` objects? For example, it is easy to send form data to any web server/script processor like this

`name=bob&job=accountant&age=30`

With `FormData` I am not actually sure what a "server" receives. Is it just a string of text like above? Or is it a more complex object that the backend must parse?

Comment: It's just a string of text like above.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data

Comment: I don't see anything about `FormData` objects there. Furthermore, any idea what order the fields are sent ? Hopefully in the order they are collected..

Comment: Start reading [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#The_method_attribute).  There is no field order, AFAIK.  Why would there be?  It's just a string containing all of the field names and values from the HTML form.  If you are looking specifically for the [FormData Interface](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), you can read more about how to use it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects).  FormData is just a "helper" object.

Comment: I care about the order. I am using an ancient embedded system, and it processes the order in a way you would never believe (first field first, last field second, and then backwards from there...)

Comment: The only way to be sure is to do a POST using the HTML in question, and see what order the fields come out.  If this proves insufficiently deterministic, then replace the fields string with one of your own before you POST, so that you can control the order.  If I were to guess, I'd say the form fields are probably processed in the order they appear in the original form element.